# Adding custom definitions file for passport-twitchtv

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to make a typescript definitions file for the package passport-twitchtv but am unable to seem to get it to find the definition.

Example definition file:

```
/// <reference types="passport"/>

import passport = require('passport');
import express = require('express');

interface Profile extends passport.Profile {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    displayName: string;
    email: string;

    _raw: string;
    _json: any;
}

interface IStrategyOptionBase {
    clientID: string;
    clientSecret: string;
    callbackURL: string;
    scope: string;
}

interface IStrategyOption extends IStrategyOptionBase {
    passReqToCallback?: false;
}

interface IStrategyOptionWithRequest  extends IStrategyOptionBase {
    passReqToCallback: true;
}

declare class Strategy extends passport.Strategy {
    constructor(options: IStrategyOption,
        verify: (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void) => void);
    constructor(options: IStrategyOptionWithRequest,
        verify: (req: express.Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void) => void);

    name: string;
    authenticate(req: express.Request, options?: Object): void;
}
```

Import method:

```
import { Strategy as TwitchStrategy } from 'passport-twitchtv';
```

I am getting the error: "Could not find a declaration file for module 'passport-twitchtv'".

If I drop the file in my node_modules/@types/passport-twitchtv it works, but I am unable to get typescript to find the .d.ts file otherwise.

I've tried adding a typeRoots to the compilerOptions in tsconfig.json, adding a typings.json file, adding "typings": "./typings/index" to the package file. Nothing I try seems to be working.

Not sure if I am supposed to declare the module when not in the node_modules/@types folder or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, either your declaration file has to be findable by the normal module resolution process or you need to declare the module like this:

```
declare module "passport-twitchtv" {
    // All your original code:
    import passport = require('passport');
    import express = require('express');

    interface Profile extends passport.Profile {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
}
```

The module resolution process looks in `node_modules/@types` (although it isn't good to modify that directory by hand since npm may blow away your changes), and you can get it to look in additional places using the `baseUrl` and `paths` compiler options; see [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

Comment: Sorry, still not really following where exactly I should be adding the `declare module "passport-twitchtv"`, and what I should be wrapping with it.